# How to fetch data from database and show it in bootstrap's modal box ( pop up ) in django respectively?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, bootstrap-4

***Technologies I'm using -->*** **Back-end** --> Python, **Web Framework** --> Django, **Front-end** --> HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4, **Database** --> SQLite3.

***What I want -->*** To display the data of each object in each bootstrap's modal box( popup ).

***The problem -->*** Data of the first object is only being shown in all the modal boxes( popups ).

Files are as follows:

**HTML template** --> `manage_requisition.html`

```html
{% extends 'hod_template/base_template.html' %}
{% block page_title %}
Manage Requisitions
{% endblock page_title %}
{% block main_content %}
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Manage Requisitions</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <!-- form start -->
                <div class="table">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
                            <th>View Requisition</th>
                        </tr>
                        {% for requisition in requisitions %}
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                                {% if requisition.requisition_status == 0 %}
                                <a style="width: 85px;" href="{% url 'supervisor_approve_requisition' requisition_id=requisition.id %}" class="btn btn-success inline" >Approve</a>
                                <a style="width: 85px;" class="btn btn-danger inline" href="{% url 'supervisor_rejected_requisition' requisition_id=requisition.id %}" >Reject</a>
                                {% elif requisition.requisition_status == 1  %}
                                 <button class="btn btn-warning" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply_modal">Approved</button>
                                {% else %}
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply_modal">Rejected</button>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reqModal">
                                    View Requisition
                                </button>
                                <div class="modal" id="reqModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="reqModal" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="reqModalTitle">Requisition Details</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p><strong>Position Required :</strong> {{ requisition.position_required }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Requirement :</strong> {{ requisition.requirement }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Candidate Name :</strong> {{ requisition.candidate_name }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Department :</strong> {{ requisition.department }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Post :</strong> {{ requisition.post }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Requirement Time Period :</strong> {{ requisition.requirement_time_period }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Work Type :</strong> {{ requisition.work_type }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Duration Start Date :</strong> {{ requisition.duration_start_date }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Duration End Date :</strong> {{ requisition.duration_end_date }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Requisition Reason :</strong> {{ requisition.requisition_reason }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Minimum Qualification :</strong> {{ requisition.min_qualification }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Maximum Qualification :</strong> {{ requisition.max_qualification }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Minimum Experience :</strong> {{ requisition.min_experience }}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Maximum Experience :</strong> {{ requisition.max_experience }}</p>
                                      </div>
                                       <div class="modal-footer">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->



          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
<!-- Modal -->
    <!-- /.content -->
{% endblock main_content %}
```

**Views file -->** `HODviews.py`

```
def Manage_Requisitions(request):
    requisitions = Requisition.objects.all()
    context = {"requisitions":requisitions}
    return render(request, "hod_template/manage_requisition.html", context)
```

**urls.py file -->** `urls.py`

`path("manage_requisition/", HODviews.Manage_Requisitions, name="manage_requisition")`

**models.py file -->** `models.py`

```
class Requisition(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
position_required = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")
requirement_choices = (
    ("New", "New"),
    ("BackFill", "BackFill")
)
requirement = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=requirement_choices, default="")
candidate_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")
department = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")
post = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")
requirement_type = (
    ("Permanent", "Permanent"),
    ("Temporary", "Temporary"),
    ("Fixed Contract", "Fixed Contract")
)
requirement_time_period = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=requirement_type, default="")
work_type = (
    ("Full-Time", "Full-Time"),
    ("Part-Time", "Part-Time")
)
work_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=work_type, default="")
duration_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
duration_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
requisition_reason = models.TextField()
min_qualification = models.CharField(max_length=1000 ,default="")
max_qualification = models.CharField(max_length=1000 ,default="")
min_experience= models.CharField(max_length=1000 ,default="")
max_experience= models.CharField(max_length=1000 ,default="")
requisition_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
objects = models.Manager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.candidate_name
```

***Image of the UI*** 
[image]

***Image of the first pop up*** 
[image]

***Image of the second popup*** 
[image]

I'm getting the data of first objet in each popup. But I want the data of every object to be displayed in each popup.

***You can contact me here*** 
***Linkedin -->*** https://www.linkedin.com/in/precioushuzaifa/

**Instagram -->** https://www.instagram.com/precious_huzaifa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is all your modals have the same id and so your buttons are just going to open the first modal they find with the ID. You need to add some sort of id to each modal. you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` to get the iteration number and attach that to the id.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reqModal-{{ forloop.counter }}">
    View Requisition
</button>
```

```
<div class="modal" id="reqModal-{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="reqModal" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and I got your point.

Comment: @Huzaifa perhaps you should consider marking this as answer as accepted if it solved your problem